# ASP.NET MVC2 depends on which version of the .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2

ASP.NET MVC2 depends on which version of the .NET Framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target your MVC 2 project to .NET 3.5 SP1 or superior. However using .NET 4.0 grants you some functionality, for example you can write `<%: someString %>` instead of `<%= Html.Encode(someString) %>`.

Comment: More feature description on Scott Gu's blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

For completeness sake:

MVC 1:

System Requirements
Supported Operating Systems: Windows Server 2003; Windows Server 2008; Windows Vista; Windows XP
.NET 3.5 SP1. Visual Studio 2008, Visual Studio 2008 SP1 or Visual Web Developer 2008 SP1 are required to use certain parts of this feature.

MVC 2 RTM:

System Requirements
Supported Operating Systems: Windows 7; Windows Server 2003; Windows Server 2008; Windows Vista; Windows XP
.NET 3.5 SP1. Visual Studio 2008, Visual Studio 2008 SP1 or Visual Web Developer 2008 SP1 are required to use certain parts of this feature.

MVC 3 Preview 1:

Supported Operating Systems: Windows 7; Windows Server 2003; Windows Server 2008; Windows Vista
.NET 4, ASP.NET 4, Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Web Developer 2010 are required to use certain parts of this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Jader, as far as i'm aware, v3.5.

jim

Answer (score 1):

The final release of ASP.NET MVC 2 is for ASP.NET 3.5